# My twitter button says "Tweeten"

Tags: twitter

I put a twitter button on my website to allow people to easily tweet pages.

The weird thing is the button says "Tweeten".  Is this a language thing?  I'm set to English NA on my computer.  I'd like it to say "Tweet".

Here's an example: http://www.trainerroad.com/cycling/rides/41452

Here's the script/HTML on the page:

```
<a  href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>    !function (d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } } (document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because your html language is set to `nl` (i.e. Dutch).

See the first line of your markup.

```
<html lang="nl" xml:lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Either change that to `en` (English) i.e.

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

or you can force twitter to display English (i.e. Twitter) by,

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweeter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

See the attribute `data-lang`